# CASE Statement in SQL query can't tell that value is not null?

Tags: sql, select, nested, case

I'm having a weird problem with a query I'm trying to run. The logic is simple enough...

```
CASE
    WHEN B.Shares IS NOT NULL 
        THEN ROUND(B.Shares/1000000.00, 2)
    ELSE Z.Float
END 'Shares',
```

For some reason, it returns the Z.Float value, completely bypassing the first WHEN operation, even though there are no null values in B.Shares.

There is a caveat here in that for the join for table A, I do a left join with an embedded select and order it by a date column desc limit 1 to get just one value from that table but even then, SQL just bypasses it in this case statement. Am I doing something wrong here? This is the full query:

```
SELECT 
    A.CustomerCode,
    CASE
        WHEN B.Shares IS NOT NULL 
            THEN ROUND(B.Shares/1000000.00, 2)
        ELSE Z.Float
    END 'Shares', 
FROM 
    schema.Customers A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * 
     FROM schema.Values 
     WHERE Currency = 'USD' 
     ORDER BY ChangedDate DESC 
     LIMIT 1) B ON B.CustomerCode = A.CustomerCode
LEFT JOIN
    schema.Floats Z ON Z.CustomerCode = A.CustomerCode
WHERE   
    A.UpdateDate = 'yyyy-mm-dd' 
GROUP BY
    A.CustomerCode 
ORDER BY
    A.CustomerCode ASC;
```

I've tried flipping around the order of the when's here and there and making it also see when B.Shares IS NULL THEN Z.Float else round(B.Shares/1000000.00, 2) but it didn't work.

Comment: Subquery B (better use more descriptive aliases), will only return a single row, so one single `B.CustomerCode`. For all other `A.CustomerCode` no row will be found, so `B.Shares` will indeed be NULL for all other rows of A.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: "...even though there are no null values in A.Shares..." -- What does `A.Shares` have to do with anything? It's not in the query.

Comment: The subquery `B` is only run once and returns a single row (last one by changed date). The predicate `B.CustomerCode = A.CustomerCode` probably never matches so you are out of luck. If you wanted this query to run once for every row in `A`, then you would need to phrase the query differently, and that depends on the specific database (and version).